# Django - grouping columns in django admin section

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-templates

I need group columns in django admin for given db table. I will take sample table 'Student' which has columns id, first_name, last_name, address1, address2, address3. So grouping will be like this:

ID -> id

NAME -> first_name, last_name

ADDRESS -> address1, address2, address3

The purpose of this to get label for set of columns when I view rows of data from a table. So When I check for the rows fetched for Student table in Django's admin section I should see something like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ID   | NAME                   | ADDRESS                                       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ID   | First Name | Last Name | Address 1       | Address 2       | Address 3 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1    | Ron        | DCunha    | 1st Cross       | Valencia        | Mangalore |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 2    | Akash      | Attavar   | Mark Street     | Attavar         | Mangalore |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I must be able achieve this in admins.py (by writing a class that extends admin.ModelAdmin).Using list_display tuple I can list out the columns that I want to see. But I do not know how to group columns. Please help me out ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you simply create a method on your Model or ModelAdmin that returns the appropriate display you want, and then use that method name in your `list_display` (it takes field names *or* callables).

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    list_display = ('id', 'full_name')

    ...

    def full_name(self, obj):
        return u'%s %s' % (obj.first_name, obj.last_name)
```

OR in your `Model` (better if the display is useful in other scenarios than the admin, otherwise use `ModelAdmin`):

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_full_name(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    list_display = ('id', 'get_full_name')
```

If you want it to be orderable, you need to define `admin_order_field` on the method, but you'll have to pick one field to use for the ordering:

```
def full_name(self, obj):
    return u'%s %s' % (obj.first_name, obj.last_name)
full_name.admin_order_field = 'last_name'
```

If you need to include HTML, specify `allow_tags=True` on the method:

```
def full_name(self, obj):
    return u'%s %s' % (obj.first_name, obj.last_name)
full_name.allow_tags = True
```

Finally, Django will compose the label automatically from the method name; in this case, it would end up being "Full name". If you want something different you can use `short_description`:

```
def full_name(self, obj):
    return u'%s %s' % (obj.first_name, obj.last_name)
full_name.short_description = "User's Full Name"
```

Comment: The way you explained is very good. Kudos to your neat explanation. It looks a like good solution but it will create a new single column with values merged from different columns. But I just want a label that will place over some set of columns that are individual having their own label. This is easily possible if you are using normal templates. But I want achieve this django's admin section itself.

Comment: That's not possible through any provided means of the admin contrib package. You might be able to cobble a solution with some serious altering of the templates and probably some view code as well, but it's more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Your's solution is the best solution available to this problem. Thanks  for your answer. I will use this solution for future projects when required.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to group columns in the exact way you described in the list view in the admin.

Your alternative at achieving almost the same result is the answer which Chris Pratt has given you.

Comment: I want to know if there is a way to display the way I asked. Other way I can think of is DOM manipulation using jQuery/Javascript. But it  will be difficult to manage when the schema changes.